# Variables with equations

Tags: linux, variable

How would I create a variable that solves an equation.
For example,

```
t=20
s=(t+30)
```

I got the t=20 pretty easy but when it came to using the echo command for s, the output ends up being 20+30 instead of being solved to get 50

For example,

```
(input)echo $s
(output)20+30
```

Comment: You should make clear which shell you want to use. Bash? Something else?

Comment: What you have offered for your example does not produce the output you claim. Instead of `20+30` it actually prints `t+30`.

Answer (score 1):

`()` runs the command inside the parentheses in a subshell, you need arithmetic expansion `$(())`:

```
$ t=20

$ s=$((t+30))

$ echo "$s"
50
```

Comment: `s=(t+20)` is an array assignment, assigning the string `t+20` to `s[0]`.  It is not a subshell unless you are using `dash` or some other `sh`-like shell without arrays.  In those other shells, the statement `s=(t+20)` would provoke a syntax error.